# Eclipse Error On Startup

Tags: eclipse, workspace, ganymede, eclipse-3.4

Eclipse was running fine last night, but this morning I tried starting it up and I came upon this error:

[alt text http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/4416/ss20100407181208.png](http://img707.imageshack.us/img707/4416/ss20100407181208.png)

Here's the log

```
!SESSION 2010-04-07 17:58:37.208 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=I20080617-2000
java.version=1.6.0_13
java.vendor=Sun Microsystems Inc.
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=en_US
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2010-04-07 17:58:37.457
!MESSAGE Startup error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.updateTable(StorageManager.java:512)
at org.eclipse.osgi.storagemanager.StorageManager.open(StorageManager.java:694)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.initFileManager(BaseStorage.java:208)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.BaseStorage.initialize(BaseStorage.java:142)
at org.eclipse.osgi.baseadaptor.BaseAdaptor.initializeStorage(BaseAdaptor.java:124)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.initialize(Framework.java:180)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.<init>(Framework.java:152)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.OSGi.createFramework(OSGi.java:90)
at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.OSGi.<init>(OSGi.java:31)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.startup(EclipseStarter.java:286)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:175)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:549)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:504)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1236)
```

Any help? I really need this up and running, and reinstalling and resetting all of my plugins and settings just isn't an option at the moment.

Comment: I suppose there is some bug in your eclipse configuration. But I do not know how to check which configuration file contains an error. `strace` would not work here I guess...

Comment: For others: you can also follow this question at http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=tree&th=165940&

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Best shot would be to use a fresh copy of eclipse and point the workspace location that you were using in the old eclipse. By this way, you will not lose your settings and will 100% avoid the startup error.

Comment: What about plugins/perspectives? I'm using it mainly to develop for Android and reloading all of the SDK's settings would be a huge pain.

Comment: Ended up doing this after I realized that my Android SDK and settings were stored in a separate folder, not with Eclipse. Plus I was two versions of Eclipse behind the latest anyways.

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue. After some debugging i tried deleting the following folders from my eclipse directory

> ./configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.manager
>   ./configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/.manager

That fixed the issue for me. No side effects. I think this is just a cache because it recreates itself on the fly. The source code doesn't seem to treat it with any special importance if it is not found, but there is a bug that [tries to parse an empty string on line 512](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.springsource.com/org.eclipse.osgi/org.eclipse.osgi/3.3.1/org/eclipse/osgi/storagemanager/StorageManager.java#StorageManager.updateTable%28%29).

Looking into the source of org.eclipse.osgi it looks like these files are somehow managed with a timestamp, so if you're doing anything that will mess with the timestamps then you'll run into this issue. I use git to manage my eclipse installation so i can revert to an earlier version if a newly installed feature starts stepping on my karma. Ran into this issue after reverting. Added it to .gitignore.

Comment: Actually it's better to just add both ./configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime and ./configuration/org.eclipse.osgi to .gitignore. These folders change everytime you open eclipse.

Comment: Hi, I've same problem here. But I can't find ./configuration/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.manager or ./configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/.manager on my workspace. Can you help me to figure it out?

Answer (score 6):

Try at least to restart eclipse with a `-clean` option.
Check also (just in case) your disk space! That can occur when not enough space is left on the disk, since the [code shows](http://demo.spars.info/j/frameset.cgi?compo_id=111749&mode=frameset&ref=3&method=454&q=xml&CASE=0&MORPHO=1&location=1111111111111111111&LANG=1) it is reading strings (supposed to be Integer) from a file.

Try also upgrading your java used to start eclipse to the latest one (u19 instead of u13)

This error stacktrace has been reported in [bug 113596](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=113596) about some version of Vista: what OS are you using, and has it been updated recently? (by Windows update for instance)

Comment: It's probably Vista. It just did something to my System in an update, but I'm not quite sure what. It enabled the UAC which I had disabled, so it could have also done something that messed with Eclipse.